# Adjust path for iTunes / Music files after files move

Tags: itunes, music, path

I moved all my music library to a network drive. So now all my library is messed up as Music (former iTunes) can not find the files. I have to manually set the path for each file I want to play (~3500) files. I tried to `grep -r '/Volumes/S_Drive/Music/Music/'` to see which file I could replace the paths in my home but it came up with nothing. So guess the music library is saved somewhere else. I would like to run this in one step instead of having to adjust paths manually every time. Cheers, EL

MacOS 11.2.3
Music 1.1.3.3

Answer (score 2):

The last time I moved my music library, I did the following:

Before starting iTunes, hold down "alt" (or "option") and then run iTunes.
This brings up a dialogue where you can tell iTunes where the library now is.[image]

Answer (score 1):

All your files should have question marks on the left like this now:
[image]

1. Double click one of them and it would prompt "The song could not be used because the original file could not be found. Would you like to locate it?" Click "Locate".
2. Find the file in the new location, and iTunes/Music App should start playing and prompt something like "Would you like to search all missing files?". Click "Yes".
3. The music App/iTunes would search and try to re-link all your music files **if the file directory tree remains the same**. For example, if the files used to be in `D:\Music\Lay\NAMANANA` and `D:\Music\Lay\SHEEP`, the new directories should not be `E:\Music\Lay\NAMANANA` and `E:\Music\Lay\2017\SHEEP`, the structrue should not be changed.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use iTunes/Music itself to move the files.

Go to Preferences->Files and press the chnage button and enter the new path. Note that this assumes that  `Keep music Media folder organised` is set.